# Why am I Getting "401 Unauthorized" for Microsoft Graph API Call?

Tags: php, microsoft-graph-api

I created the app in Tenant A and added it to Tenant B. I have granted the permissions in both tenants. Why am I getting this response every time I make an API call to the app?

```
resulted in a `401 Unauthorized` response: {"error":{"code":"NoPermissionsInAccessToken","message":"The token contains no permissions, or permissions can not be un (truncated...)
```

Here is the PHP request that I'm making (I am using the client id and client secret from the app in Tenant A):

```
<?php

use League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Exception\IdentityProviderException;

use Microsoft\Graph\Graph;

$guzzle = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

$tenantId = 'common';
$clientId = 'ccc-ddd-fff';
$clientSecret = 'xxx-yyy-zzz';

$url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' . $tenantId . '/oauth2/token?api-version=1.0';

try {
    $token = json_decode($guzzle->post($url, [
        'form_params' => [
            'client_id' => $clientId,
            'client_secret' => $clientSecret,
            'resource' => 'https://graph.microsoft.com/',
            'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
        ],
    ])->getBody()->getContents());

    $accessToken = $token->access_token;

} catch (\Exception $e) {
    print $e->getMessage();
}

$graph = new Graph();
$graph->setAccessToken($accessToken);

try {
    print_r($graph->createRequest("GET", '/users/email@email.com/messages/xxxxxxxxxxxxx==')->execute());
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    print $e->getMessage();
}
```

Both tenants have these permissions granted:
[Permissions in Tenant A and B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqsZJ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I needed to do was prompt the Microsoft admin to grant permissions using a link similar to this one. Merely adding the enterprise from the Microsoft

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?scope=offline_access+openid+profile+User.Read+Mail.ReadWrite+Mail.Send
&response_type=code
&client_id=a62b0808-2b1f-4efc-a3d6-ad1223dc06a9
&redirect_uri=https://myurl/blah.html
&response_mode=query
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, according to the [api document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions), you'd better to add `Mail.ReadBasic.All` application permission, but I'm not sure if it influenced your calling here.

Your issue mainly came from that you used `$tenantId = 'common';`, you should set it as the tenant name (such as xxx.onmicrosoft.com) you'd like to calling the api for. I mean that if you wanna call `/users/xxx@tenantA.com/messages`, you should put tenantA's tenant id/name to the `$tenantId` variable, but when you wanna call `/users/yyy@tenantB.com/messages`, you should set tenantB's.

Screenshot below showed the scenario when I used a token generated by `common` but not my tenant name.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the info! I don't think I did a very good job of explaining my setup, but the app that I created in Tenant A is a multi-tenant app. So, I thought I should be able to use /common for the tenant id. I'm trying to figure out a way to make the API calls without knowing what Tenant B's tenant id is. So is there some way from inside Tenant B to grant the permissions to Tenant A's app and use /common as the tenant id?

Comment: Actually, the app I used to generate my access token for testing is also a multi-tenant application which created in my tenant, and I used `common` to generate a token to call api for getting messages from user which also belongs to my tenant but failed. So per my test, it's forbidden. And in another term, when using multi-tenant app to generate token for getting data from different tenants, it's supposed to set an exact tenant for security consideration so that graph api can know the resource you called comes from which tenant and then provide the response.

Comment: By the way, if you decode the access token generated by `common`, you'll find that there's no api permission contained in the token, that means the api will find the token doesn't contain the correct permission, so the request will be forbidden. You can try decode it yourself to check it : )

Answer (score 0):

401 Unauthorized error: Is your token valid?

Make sure that your application is presenting a valid access token to Microsoft Graph as part of the request. This error often means that the access token may be missing in the HTTP authenticate request header or that the token is invalid or has expired. We strongly recommend that you use the Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL) for access token acquisition. Additionally, this error may occur, if you try to use a delegated access token granted to a personal Microsoft account, to access an API that only supports work or school accounts (organizational accounts).

You can always leverage [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms/) to check claims on your token. Use this and check if you have the necessary permissions to call an API endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

401 Unauthorized error: You need to get accesstoken with user login.
So you must change

```
'form_params' => [
  'client_id'     => $client_id,
  'client_secret' => $client_secret,
  'scope'         => 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default',
  'grant_type'    => 'password',
  'top'           => 999,
  'username'      => "email@domain",
  'password'      => "yourpass"
],
```